# rewrite multiple inline return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method that will return an error or an user, depends on the status of the user, like this

```
  def authenticate
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:mail].downcase)
    return render json: Errors::EMAIL_NOT_EXISTS, status: 404 if user.nil?
    return render json: Errors::WRONG_EMAIL_PASSWORD_COMBINATION, status: 403 unless user.valid_password?(params[:password])
    return render json: Errors::EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED, status: 202 if 'active' != user.activation_state
    render json: user, only: %w(access_token first_name last_name), status: 201
  end
```

I'm losing sleep because I think it is too ugly, and **should** have a better way to handle with multiple return possibilities but I can't see one.
How can I make this better readable without use multiple returns or multiple ifs

Comment: the first condition , think, will alway be false, since find_by raises an Exception when found not the records

Comment: You could also use [ActiveModel Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to specify which `user` fields to render as JSON, so that you won't have to specify them inside the controller.

Comment: `find_by` does not raise exception if no records found. it will be nil. So all good @МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: if I use `find_by!` it will raise

Comment: @LuizE. Indeed! :)

Comment: @ksarunas ok ) it is not a `!` version right =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the case suggestion above, but there's nothing wrong with using `if`.  However, the `if` approach would be way clearer if you did not use the single line form of if. In addition, the return keywords would not be necessary, since in Ruby you can assign the result of an if expression to a variable, or simply let it be the return value of the method because it was the last expression evaluated.  You could code it like this:

```
def authenticate

  user = User.find_by(email: params[:mail].downcase)

  stuff = if user.nil?
    { json: Errors::EMAIL_NOT_EXISTS, status: 404 }
  else unless user.valid_password?(params[:password])
    { json: Errors::WRONG_EMAIL_PASSWORD_COMBINATION, status: 403 }
  else if 'active' != user.activation_state
    { json: Errors::EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED, status: 202 }
  else
    { json: user, only: %w(access_token first_name last_name), status: 201 }
  end

  render stuff
end
```

An example of using the result of an if expression as the return value of a method is at https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/6876886030c7d6cf80d1b6fbcfebf7ae.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this

```
status, error_details = case
  when user.nil?
    [404, Errors::EMAIL_NOT_EXISTS]
  when !user.valid_password?(params[:password])
    [403, Errors::EMAIL_NOT_EXISTS]
  when 'active' != user.activation_state
    [202, Errors::EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED]
  else
    [201, nil]
end

return render json: user, only: %w(access_token first_name last_name), status: status if error_details.blank?

render json: error_details, status: status
```

Answer (score 1):

How about case with condition here?

```
case
when user.nil?
  render json: Errors::EMAIL_NOT_EXISTS, status: 404
when !user.valid_password?(params[:password])
  render json: Errors::WRONG_EMAIL_PASSWORD_COMBINATION, status: 403
when 'active' != user.activation_state
  render json: Errors::EMAIL_NOT_VERIFIED, status: 202
else
  render json: user, only: %w(access_token first_name last_name), status: 201
end
```

Of course you could have a presenter to move all the logic outside of controller later, just the idea.